# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Tags: python

My code:`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open("a.dat", "r") as ins:
    array = []
    for line in ins:
        l=line.strip()
        array.append(l)

a1 = array[:,1]
print a1
```

I want to read a.dat as array then take the first column.What is wrong?

Comment: Why are you writing `array[:,1]` instead of `array[1]` (or possibly `array[0]`)?

Comment: L3viathan is correct, drop the ",". Also array is confusing terminology in python they are "lists".

Comment: You are using numpy syntax on a python list

Comment: Yes,thanks.But a.dat is (1484,2).If I follow  advice from L#viathan,I get: 94.0700    2878.2500
Actually I want 1484 values.

Comment: You're treating a regular `list` as if it was a `numpy.array` - if you want that behaviour, use `numpy`.

Comment: You're also not splitting the string on anything, so your lists only have 1 column.

Comment: @Chinmay Kanchi Then what should I do to read a.dat as two columns matrix and then select the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loading numerical data, it's often useful to use `numpy` instead of just Python.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.loadtxt('a.dat')
print arr[:,0]
```

`numpy` is a Python library that's very well suited to loading and manipulating numerical data (with a bonus that when used correctly, it's waaaay faster than using Python lists). In addition, for dealing with tabular data with mixed datatypes, I recommend using `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.load_csv('a.dat', sep=' ', names=['col1', 'col2'])
print df['col1']
```

Numpy can be found [here](http://www.numpy.org)

Pandas can be found [here](http://pandas.pydata.org)

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong: `a1 = array[:,1]` putting values separated with comma make it a Tuple of 2 values. You should use:

```
a1 = array[0]
```

To get first row or to get first column use:

```
column = [row[0] for row in array]
```

Comment: I think it does:
`array = ['abc', 'abc', 'abc']`
`[row[0] for row in array]`
`['a', 'a', 'a']`

Comment: I am pasting first lines of a.dat
     94.0700    2878.2500
     95.1250    2878.7500
     86.4450    2880.2500
     86.7620    2883.5000
     67.9860    2882.2500
    150.5570    2872.0000
    276.3130    2862.2500

Comment: Please paste these into your answer inside a code block. Line breaks don't show up in comments, so it's hard to see what your data file looks like.